# How to get metadata of an SQL query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metadata

I know how to read metadata for existing DB table using SQL Alchemy:

```
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)
meta.reflect(schema="schema_name", views=True, resolve_fks=False)
res = meta.tables["table_name"]
```

#### Question:

How can I get metadata or column types for an SQL query (`select * from tab1 join tab2 on tab1.id = tab2.id`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute an query using sqlalchemy Core (not ORM), you will will be returned an instance of [`ResultProxy`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) object.

`ResultProxy` is a wrapper over the underlying DBAPI cursor, and if the driver to the RDBMS your code uses is implemented in compliance with [PEP 249 -- Python Database API Specification v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) or [PEP 248 -- Python Database API Specification v1.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0248), you should be access the underlying `ResultProxy.cursor` object, which in turn should have [`.description`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) property.

Therefore, code similar to below should just work:

```
res = session.execute(my_sql_statement)
columns = res.cursor.description
for col in columns:
    print(col.name, col.type_code, col.display_size, col.internal_size, col.precision, col.scale, col.null_ok)
```

---

For small query like `SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".name AS user_name, "group".id AS group_id, "group".name AS group_name  FROM "user" JOIN user_group AS user_group_1 ON "user".id = user_group_1.user_id JOIN "group" ON "group".id = user_group_1.group_id`, here is the output I see for PostgreSQL database:

```
user_id 23 None 4 None None None
user_name 1043 None 250 None None None
group_id 23 None 4 None None None
group_name 1043 None 250 None None None
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Do you have an idea how can get a generic sqlalchemy column types out of dialect specific ones? For example: `cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR` --> `sqlalchemy.types.VARCHAR`

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit of a hack, but one approach would be to create a temporary table using the query and then reflect the table. Example for mssql:

```py
with engine.begin() as con:
    original_query = """\
    SELECT c.name as firstname, p.lastname 
    FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c
        ON c.parent_id = p.id
    """
    con.execute(
        sa.text(f"SELECT TOP 1 q.* INTO #tmp FROM ({original_query}) q")
    )
    con.commit()
    tmp = sa.Table("#tmp", sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)
    for col in tmp.columns:
        print(repr(col))
    """console output:
    Column('firstname', NVARCHAR(length=100), table=<#tmp>, nullable=False)
    Column('lastname', VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'), table=<#tmp>)
    """
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had this idea, but I want the solution to be DB independent and for different DB the "create temporary table" statement might look differently. And I wouldn't like to create a regular table as it might pollute the DB and in Oracle it could cause a problem with overflowing the internal object id sequence if we would call it too often.